# How does gp_camera_file_get work?

Tags: c++, c, memory, libgphoto2

I'm new to libgphoto2 and had some questions about where the actual image memory is located. It seems that photos are accessed via an object called a `CameraFile`. There's an example included in the source called sample-capture.c that has a function called `capture_to_memory`.

In that function, a CameraFile object is created and initialized using `gp_file_new`. The implementation of `gp_file_new` creates a `CameraFile` object whose accesstype member is set to `GP_FILE_ACCESSTYPE_MEMORY`.

That `CameraFile` object is then passed to `gp_camera_file_get`, and I'm not really clear what happens in this function.

After the call to `gp_camera_file_get`, the file is sent to `gp_file_get_data_and_size`. Looking at the implementation of that function, and given that the files accesstype is `GP_FILE_ACCESSTYPE_MEMORY`, the `gp_file_get_data_and_size` function will not allocate any memory and instead merely assign the pointer to the CameraFile's data member (same with size).

So where is the memory this pointer points to? Is it on the actual camera? Or is it somewhere in my ram? I'm just trying to avoid as many memory operations as possible. I've found a nice blog post

http://sepharads.blogspot.com/2011/11/camera-tethered-capturing-using.html?m=1

where the `CameraFile` object is created via `gp_file_new_from_fd`. This sets the files accesstype to `GP_FILE_ACCESSTYPE_FD`. When `gp_file_get_data_and_size` is called on a file with this accesstype, new memory is allocated and the file's data is copied into it. However, this is read from disk, or at least I assume it is since FD means Unix File Descriptor, and it needs an actual filename string. Does that mean that `gp_camera_file_get` reads the data into a file on disk if the CameraFile's accestype is `GP_FILE_ACCESSTYPE_FD`?

There is a function called `gp_file_free`. If it's an FD file it closes the file handle, but it doesn't call `free(file->data)` anywhere, so I'm pretty confused...

What does `gp_camera_file_get` do? The implementation is there, but it kind of threw me. Does it actually bring the file from my camera's memory to my computer's memory and allocate `CameraFile->data` in ram? Or does it just give me a handle to something stored on my camera?

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask, I did see some sort of mailing list for libgphoto2 but I couldn't tell how active it was.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I think I've found it.

So `gp_camera_file_get` ends up calling `gp_filesystem_get_file`, which calls `gp_filesystem_get_file_impl`. That function looks at the `CameraFileType`, and if it's `GP_FILE_TYPE_NORMAL` (which it is, in my case), it calls `gp_file_copy` with an instance of CameraFileSystemFile as the source.

`gp_file_copy` ends up calling `malloc` if `GP_FILE_ACCESSTYPE_MEMORY` is the destination file's accesstype, and writes to disk if the accesstype is `GP_FILE_ACCESSTYPE_FD`.

Then, the call to `gp_file_free` calls `gp_file_clean`, which calls `free` if the accesstype is `GP_FILE_ACCESSTYPE_MEMORY`.